# Pandas grouping rows and inserting headers for each group

Tags: pandas

I am trying to reshape high school transcript data.  My data looks like this:

| sname | year | term | mark | course |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| school1 | 2020-2021 | 1 | F | Class1 |
| school1 | 2020-2021 | 1 | F | Class2 |
| school1 | 2020-2021 | 1 | D | Class3 |
| school2 | 2021-2022 | 2 | B- | Class4 |
| school2 | 2021-2022 | 2 | C- | Class5 |
| school3 | 2021-2022 | 2 | F | Class6 |

...

but I want something like this

| mark | course |
| --- | --- |
| 2020-2021 term 1 school 1 |  |
| F | Class1 |
| F | Class2 |
| D | Class3 |
| 2021-2022 term 1 school 2 |  |
| B- | Class4 |
| C- | Class5 |
| 2021-2022 term 2 school 3 |  |
| F | Class6 |
| B+ | Class7 |
| 2022-2023 term 1 school 1 |  |
| F | Class8 |
| F | Class9 |
| D | Class10 |

I've tried groupby, pivot, stack/unstack. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like you want to `.set_index(['year', 'term', 'sname'])` then use styling to get the headers, but I don't know how to do that off the top of my head.

Comment: hi steve, I would question if this is a good idea, given that pandas is designed for data analysis, not for data presentation. You're combining four different data types into one columns, which gives me a migraine. Please kindly reconsider doing this

Comment: @Mark That's what [styling](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/style.html) is for :)

Comment: @wjandrea Your scientists were so preoccupied with whether they could, they didn't stop to think if they should :P

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea either. You should not mix the label/index of the data and the data itself.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  Turns out groupby() returns an object that holds a list of tuples.  The first item in each tuple are the groupBy values and the second item is the dataframe. So I can style them in for loop. First the header, then the DF!

Answer (score 0):

With [`GroupBy.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.apply.html) / [`concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html) :

```
def subheader(g):
    vals = {"mark": "{0} term {1} {2}".format(*g.name), "course": ""}
    return pd.concat([pd.DataFrame([vals]), g], ignore_index=True)
    
    
out = (df.groupby(["year", "term", "sname"],
        group_keys=False)[["mark", "course"]].apply(subheader))
```

Output :

```
print(out)

                       mark  course
0  2020-2021 term 1 school1        
1                         F  Class1
2                         F  Class2
3                         D  Class3
0  2021-2022 term 2 school2        
1                        B-  Class4
2                        C-  Class5
0  2021-2022 term 2 school3        
1                         F  Class6
```